# Having trouble with Java's FileChooser

Tags: java

I am working on a science research project and instead of using Excel I wanted to analyze data with my own code. I save a *'.txt'* file with 10,000 data points inside separated by tabs and hard returns. Now, I am trying to use this snippet of code to better select the file for review, but it never actually get the file for me to send using `getFile()`, my question is: Why does it loop forever and never get the file for use?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleFileChooser extends JFrame {
    public File sf;
    public SimpleFileChooser() {
        super("File Selector");
        setSize(350, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton openButton = new JButton("Open");
        final JLabel statusbar = new JLabel("Select a File");
        openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(SimpleFileChooser.this);
                if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    sf = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                }
            }
        });
        c.add(openButton);
        c.add(statusbar);
    }

    public File getFile(){
        return sf;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Why does it loop forever and never get the file for use?` Where?

Comment: There are no loops in the code you've posted.

Comment: Without seeing how you invoke this code I can't say for sure, but my hunch is that you think that `JFrame`s are modal (they aren't), and are trying to call `getFile()` before one has been chosen.

Comment: This is how I invoke the code: `SimpleFileChooser sfc = new SimpleFileChooser();  sfc.setVisible(true);   
Trial test = new Trial(sfc.getFile());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an `ActionListener` to trigger the file selection if the user presses the `openButton`. This listener won't block your current thread (the action event is running on the [*Event Dispatch Thread*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)), so you can complete the instantiation of `SimpleFileChooser` and then call `#getFile()` before the user had a chance to select a file.

You can either build some stuff around your code to make it wait for the action event to happen, or you can get rid of that frame and the listener, since you don't need them:

```
 public class SimpleFileChooser {
      private final JFileChooser chooser;

      public SimpleFileChooser() {
           chooser = new JFileChooser();
           chooser.setDialogTitle("Select a File");
      }

      public File getFile() {
           int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
           if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                return chooser.getSelectedFile();
           }
           return null;
      }
 }
```

You can call it like you already do:

```
SimpleFileChooser sfc = new SimpleFileChooser();
Trial test = new Trial(sfc.getFile());
```

Since you can call `#getFile()` more than once, you should reuse the `SimpleFileChooser` instance, because its creation is kind of expensive.

Comment: No, a `JFrame` does not start in its own thread. All Swing UI code is executed in the event dispatch thread.

Comment: @yole Right ... I updated the first paragraph to be more clear on that point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how are you calling `getFile()`. Are you sure that you are using the same instance of `SimpleFileChooser` all the time?
To make sure the problem is not the `getSelectedFile()` method, what I think isn't, you can show a message with the `sf.getName()` results right after have updated sf variable.